# Problem with query in "Database System Concepts 7th ed" by Silberschatz

Tags: mysql, sqlite, mariadb

I'm having trouble with learning databases right at the first lap.

On page 104 of Silberschatz, he presents this query when explaining subqueries.

```
select dept_name, avg_salary
from (select dept_name, avg (salary)
      from instructor
      group by dept_name)
      as dept_avg (dept_name, avg_salary)
where avg_salary > 42000;
```

However, this code doesn't work in my system, which I later learned is actually MariaDB rather than MySQL. I'm also using Adminer.
The error is as follows

```
Error in query (1064): Syntax error near '(dept_name, avg_salary) where avg_salary > 42000' at line 5
```

I'm using BunsenLabs Lithium, which doesn't support MySQL or phpMyAdmin, so I can't switch without reinstalling my whole system.

I've run this query through two syntax validators.

This one
https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/
said the query was fine, but poorly optimized.

This one
https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/
Gave the same invalid syntax error as my system.

However, Silberschatz made a browser based SQL command line based on SQLite to query the same database that the book uses. I ran his query as it was written in the book into the command line
https://www.db-book.com/db7/university-lab-dir/sqljs.html, which throws a similar error

```
Uncaught Error: near "(": syntax error
```

MySQL/MariaDB version : mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.23-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Does anyone know what's going on? Thank you for your time

Comment: The first error message does not match the query above it.

Comment: @Shadow 
sorry wrong query, corrected.

Comment: Wel, this is not mysql syntax.

Comment: Which database distribution syntax is it?

Comment: This syntax is valid in SQL Server: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2a7d9b27b69b219a79bd0f290cc71897 and Postgresql: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2a7d9b27b69b219a79bd0f290cc71897

Comment: I see, does this mean I wouldn't be able to use Silberschatz if I wanted to develop practical MySQL skills? Or rather, that a book more specifically teaching MySQL would be a better pick as a self teaching beginner?

Comment: It looks like this book does not use features of a specific rdbms. So probably you must find something else.

Comment: I see, thank you. I guess I'll close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [reference](https://modern-sql.com/feature/table-column-aliases) describing various methods to indicate table and column aliases, which include column aliases in the from clause:

> Renaming columns in the from clause was already required by intermediate level SQL-92 but has become a mandatory feature with SQL:1999.4 Its adoption is poor nevertheless.

The linked site indicates that mariadb does not support this syntax at all, while mysql has limited support for it in case of derived tables.